# android textview clickable compoundDrawable

Tags: android, textview

I can set images to the left or right of a textview in 2 ways:

1. using `android:drawableLeft`
2. using a linearlayout and adding imageview and textview seperately

If I use 1 then is there any way to listen to clicks on the drawable ?

Comment: Do you want to implement listener separately for textView and ImageView or the same for all.

Comment: seperately for textview and imageview obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that so far there's now way to make the compound drawables of textview to be clickable

Answer (score 0):

I think the second approach will be more better than the first one and there will be no issue for adding the listener to both the view separately.

Answer (score 0):

For workaround we can use onTouchListener

```java
mTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getX() > view.getWidth() - DisplayUtils.DpToPx(HomeScreen.this, 50)) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(<context>, "clicked right drawable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

DpToPx method is

```
public static int DpToPx(final Context context, final int dp) {
    Resources r = context.getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```